# How to boot FreeBSD system with broken bootcode?

Tags: boot, freebsd, mbr

I have an HDD (or SSD, or flash drive) with FreeBSD installed on it, and somehow I broke the bootcode (first 446 bytes of MBR). How could I boot into this FreeBSD?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that there is 512-byte DOS-like MBR, and you have replaced first 446 bytes of it with some crap ([zeros](https://gist.github.com/rc5hack/b8f130b4bc1ae26307df) or just `/dev/urandom` output), or damaged the bootcode some other way. In this case MBR partition table is on it's place, but system cannot boot from this device.

Idea is to use other BSD-like system's loader to boot with your device and your kernel.

- You should start booting to any BSD-like OS (I have tried with FreeBSD 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 9.2 and Frenzy 1.4) from another HDD, CD, flash drive, PXE, virtual media via BMC/KVM, etc.
- During boot process hit "Escape to loader prompt" option on loader screen (it would be "6" in older FreeBSD systems, "3" in FreeBSD 9, "8" in Frenzy)
- Unload kernel and it's modules by typing `unload`
- Find out the device you want to boot your FreeBSD from (usually something like `disk0s1a`) by typing `lsdev`
- Set this device "current" by typing `set currdev="disk0s1a"`
- Re-read `loder.conf` from your device (to be sure that all your kernel tunings and hacks would apply) by typing `read-conf boot/loader.conf`
- Start OS and enjoy - just type `boot-conf`

When your OS starts, you could repair bootcode. I use `sysinstall` for it (Custom -> Partition, <kbd>W</kbd>, `<Yes>`,  `BootMgr` ("Install the FreeBSD Boot Manager"), `<OK>`, <kbd>Q</kbd>, `<Exit>`, `<Exit Install>`), but it is deprecated since 9.0-RELEASE and removed from base since 10.0-RELEASE. Other way is to use backup, stored in `/boot`, to extract bootcode from it:

```
# gpart bootcode -b /boot/mbr /dev/yourbootdevice
```